# Application.Exit() which operation is first

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I read the docs on MSDN for Application.Exit(), it says:

*Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.*

In my understanding, to inform all message pump to terminate, this method would finally post a WM_QUIT message to the application message queue. And after posted the message, the method then would close each window(by MSDN). The problem is arising here, when this method try to close each window, the WM_QUIT message should have not been processed, but the MSDN said "it closes all windows **after** the *messages* have been processed".

It seems the documentation is contradictory to my inference. What is the problem here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the WM_QUIT message would not have been processed?

Comment: A better question would be, "What problem are you having due to this order of operations concern?"

Comment: There's no single question mark in the QUESTION...

Comment: @IcyBrk you should really have posted your answer as a comment, but don't worry, I've added a snippet about `ExitThreadCore` to the post below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting question; using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx), let's have a look at what `Application.Exit()` does:

We see that the critical method is `ExitInternal`

```
private static bool ExitInternal()
{
    bool flag = false;
    lock (Application.internalSyncObject)
    {
        if (Application.exiting)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Application.exiting = true;
        try
        {
            if (Application.forms != null)
            {
                foreach (Form form in Application.OpenFormsInternal)
                {
                    if (form.RaiseFormClosingOnAppExit())
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                if (Application.forms != null)
                {
                    while (Application.OpenFormsInternal.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Application.OpenFormsInternal[0].RaiseFormClosedOnAppExit();
                    }
                }
                Application.ThreadContext.ExitApplication();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Application.exiting = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

If everything goes well, the application will *first* close all forms, then close any forms it missed, and then, finally, it calls `Application.ThreadContext.ExitApplication();`

As part of  ExitApplication, we see the cleanup:

```
private static void ExitCommon(bool disposing)
{
    lock (Application.ThreadContext.tcInternalSyncObject)
    {
        if (Application.ThreadContext.contextHash != null)
        {
            Application.ThreadContext[] array = new Application.ThreadContext[Application.ThreadContext.contextHash.Values.Count];
            Application.ThreadContext.contextHash.Values.CopyTo(array, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i].ApplicationContext != null)
                {
                    array[i].ApplicationContext.ExitThread();
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i].Dispose(disposing);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
/// <summary>Terminates the message loop of the thread.</summary>
/// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
public void ExitThread()
{
    this.ExitThreadCore();
}
```

What does [ExitThreadCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.exitthreadcore.aspx) do?

Well, it doesn't directly kill the thread, but it does start the process:

> ExitThread and ExitThreadCore do not actually cause the thread to
>   terminate. These methods raise the ThreadExit event to which the
>   Application object listens. The Application object then terminates the
>   thread.

However, the really interesting bit seems to happen in `array[i].Dispose(disposing)`

As part of this method, we see:

```
if (this.messageLoopCount > 0 && postQuit)
{
    this.PostQuit();
}
```

PostQuit() is what sends the `WM_QUIT` message. So we should also consider when `Application.ThreadContext.Dispose` is called, and it is always seems to be after the forms have closed, although I'm happy to be corrected there.

So the order seems to be close all forms, then send the WM_QUIT message. I think you are right, the documentation may actually have the events in the wrong order...

It also confirms another side effect we often see; when an application is closed but there is still a thread running in the background, the exe will still be in the list of running applications. The forms have been closed, but there is still that rogue thread, humming along preventing the Exit() from completing.

As [Tergiver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351385/tergiver) mentions:

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.

(from [Thread.IsBackgroundThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx))

I also wondered what `Environment.Exit` does:

```
[SecurityCritical, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("QCall", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern void _Exit(int exitCode);
```

It effectively calls out to the OS to kill the process; this will terminate all windows with little grace; the OnFormClosing will probably never get to fire for example. As part of this wholesale termination, it will also [I hesitate to use attempt as I've never seen it fail] kill any threads including the 'main' thread the message loop is running on.

Comment: +1 nice sleuthing. The reason your "rogue thread" leaves the process open is because it is **not** running in the background, it's a foreground thread. The process cannot terminate until all foreground threads terminate. That's why you should set your "background" threads `IsBackground` property to `true`.

Comment: Thanks dash, you clarify the fact,and thank you for your detailed digging, I still have a doubt,could you let me know what exactly ExitThreadCore() does, I try to read the source code by using Reflector, but not very successful.